# Is it possible to manually define a conversion for an enum class?

Tags: c++, enums, c++11, enum-class

Normally you can define a cast for a class by using the following syntax:

```
class Test {
public:
  explicit operator bool() { return false; }
};
```

Is there a way to do this or something similar for an `enum class`?

Comment: If you did that, what would be the point of using `enum class` at all? `enum` can be forward declared, given an underlying type, and is scoped with the enumeration name. If you can freely convert them from/to integers... why use an `enum class` at all? Because it's new?

Comment: Because I still don't want to have the `enum class` convert to an integer, but I would be able to define it to be able to be converted to a `bool`, and have specific values evaluate to true and others to false.

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as an "implicit cast". A cast is something you write in your source code. It tells the compiler to do a conversion. So a cast is an explicit conversion. The compiler can also do some conversions without a cast; those are known as "implicit conversions".

Comment: @NicolBolas I was googling here because I would have liked implicit conversion to bool, where one enum is SUCCESS and the others are error-codes. Obviously, one can put in a comparison, but with the variable names as they were it wasn't needed for clarity.

Comment: Hmm... one case would be a set of flags for bitwise operations using a C-style bitfield, @NicolBolas.  For a class e.g., `MyCBitfield`, It would allow the programmer to define the conversion as `static_cast<MyCBitfield::underlying_type>(1) << bitflag` while preventing conversion to `int`.  (Although, at that point, you're admittedly better off making the type constructible from the enum, or providing an assignment operator.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, it's not.

Actually, an `enum class` is no class at all. The `class` keyword is only used because suddenly changing the unscoped `enum` to a scoped `enum` would have mean reworking *all* enums codes. So the committee decided that to distinguish between new-style and old-style enums, the new ones would be tagged with `class`, because it's a keyword already so no `enum` could have been named `class` in C++. They could have picked another, it would not have made much more sense anyway.

However, despite the `class` keyword they are still regular enums in that only enumerators (and potentially values assigned to them) are allowed within the brackets.

Comment: `enum class` was first used with nearly the same semantics by C++/CLI.  The Standard adopted the existing syntax and standardized it.

Comment: Makes sense.  Too bad C++/CLI hadn't used `enum namespace`, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 20):

No, but you can make a normal class type act like an enum class, using `constexpr` members and constructors.  And then you can add all the additional member functions you want.

---

Proof that it can work even with `switch`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct FakeEnum
{
    int x;

    constexpr FakeEnum(int y = 0) : x(y) {}

    constexpr operator int() const { return x; }

    static const FakeEnum A, B, Z;
};

constexpr const FakeEnum FakeEnum::A{1}, FakeEnum::B{2}, FakeEnum::Z{26};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& st, FakeEnum& fe)
{
    int val;
    st >> val;
    fe = FakeEnum{val};
    return st;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    FakeEnum fe;
    std::cin >> fe;

    switch (fe)
    {
        case FakeEnum::A:
        std::cout << "A\n";
        break;
        case FakeEnum::B:
        std::cout << "B\n";
        break;
        case FakeEnum::Z:
        std::cout << "Z\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Proof that working with `switch` does not require implicit interconversion with `int`:

```
#include <iostream>

/* pseudo-enum compatible with switch and not implicitly convertible to integral type */
struct FakeEnum
{
    enum class Values { A = 1, B = 2, Z = 26 };
    Values x;

    explicit constexpr FakeEnum(int y = 0) : FakeEnum{static_cast<Values>(y)} {}
    constexpr FakeEnum(Values y) : x(y) {}

    constexpr operator Values() const { return x; }
    explicit constexpr operator bool() const { return x == Values::Z; }

    static const FakeEnum A, B, Z;
};

constexpr const FakeEnum FakeEnum::A{Values::A}, FakeEnum::B{Values::B}, FakeEnum::Z{Values::Z};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& st, FakeEnum& fe)
{
    int val;
    st >> val;
    fe = FakeEnum(val);
    return st;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    FakeEnum fe;
    std::cin >> fe;

    switch (fe)
    {
        case FakeEnum::A:
        std::cout << "A\n";
        break;
        case FakeEnum::B:
        std::cout << "B\n";
        break;
        case FakeEnum::Z:
        std::cout << "Z\n";
        break;
    }
    // THIS ERRORS: int z = fe;
}
```

Comment: Boost is a good example of this -- look at the part for non-C++11 (`BOOST_NO_SCOPED_ENUMS` is defined) and extend that -- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/boost/detail/scoped_enum_emulation.hpp

Comment: “you can make a normal class type act like an enum class” — Unfortunately you *can’t*, in C++, because C++’ `switch` is stupid (it’s also hard/impossible to make it into a POD while preserving sane invariants such as private constructor).

Comment: @KonradRudolph You can make your class `switch`-able if you define a single conversion function to integral or enumeration type. What do you mean by "`switch` is stupid"? (if you recall what point you were trying to make there)

Comment: @villapx It’s stupid because it only works on integral constant values for no good reason other than its history. Modern languages have `switch` statements that are vastly more useful by supporting custom types and powerful pattern matching. By contrast, unless you’re writing (or, more likely auto-generating) a state machine on integer states, the `switch` statement offers virtually no advantage over an `if` statement with multiple `if else` branches.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Other languages are stupid because they provide two different features through a single keyword.  There is absolutely nothing wrong with providing an efficient jump-table control flow construct, as C and C++ do with `switch`.  There is also nothing wrong with providing a pattern-match-based control flow construct.  Most modern language do NOT have `switch` statements that act as you describe -- most have "match expressions" or "case statements" or "when" or "select" or....  There is nothing about the word `switch` that implies pattern-matching support.

Comment: @BenVoigt That doesn’t change the fact that the `switch` statement in C++ is seriously stunted in its capabilities without valid technical reason. Modern C++ strives to provide *high-level*, versatile constructs that work with custom types. `switch` is the diametric opposite of that.

Comment: C++ strives to provide high-level features at the same time as maintaining direct access to the machine ("better assembly language").  The designers have said *many* times, that C++ is multi-paradigm.  `switch` is direct access to a jump-table, exactly like it is in C.  And a systems-programming language *should* have direct access.  I think it would be great if someday C++ does add some pattern matching operators, but it would be a horrible mistake if they used the `switch` keyword for that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Meanwhile, your comments are wrong starting with your very first assumption.  `switch` does work with custom pseudo-enum types just as it does with true `enum` and `enum class` types.

Comment: @BenVoigt This design principle stopped being true a long time ago. Even C no longer provides a close-to-the-metal model for modern CPU architectures, *and that’s OK*. Creating a jump table from a list of alternatives is a (trivial) job for the optimising compiler, not the programmer. Your `FakeEnum` example is nice but it breaks several of the conditions I’d have for a strongly typed enum, in particular implicit conversion to `int` (which is required for it to work with `switch`), which means it loses most of the benefits of being its own type.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: You continue to make comments which are grounded in your lack of imagination, not facts.  I chose the combination of "enumerators nested inside the type name" and "implicit conversion to `int`".  When you define your own pseudo-enumerators, you can decide both of those independently (unlike `enum` vs `enum class` where the choices are linked).  If you want explicit bool but not implicit conversions to/from `int`, [here you are](https://rextester.com/MGJQK39909)

Comment: @BenVoigt You misunderstand me: I want *no* implicit conversion; and I want a 
`StrongEnum` base class that I can inherit from CRTP style to obtain a new, strongly-typed “enum”, without having to write manual code. These are not unreasonable requirements (I’d call them *minimal* acceptable requirements, in fact), but they preclude use inside a `switch`.

Comment: And, just to clarify: I’d be OK with having an implicit conversion to a non-visible `enum class` as an implementation detail (in your example this would correspond to making `Value` private) because that conversion could never be triggered by accident, the type being unaccessible. However, I see no way of getting this to work with CRTP without having to write this manually for every custom enum type and this is something I really find unacceptable.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Note that the values `A`, `B`, `Z`, don't actually have to exist in the secret enum class type... an enum class object is (unlike a legacy enum) guaranteed to be able to store the same set of values as its underlying type, whether or not they are part of the closure of enumerators under bitwise-OR.

Comment: @BenVoigt I see where you are going with this. Indeed, CRTP can be kind-of made to work with this.

Comment: Isn't ```constexpr const``` redundant?

Answer (score 5):

You cant define non-member cast operators in C++. And you certainly cant define member functions for enums.
So I suggest you do free functions to convert your enum to other types, the same way you would implement cast operators.

e.g.

```
bool TestToBool(enum_e val)
{
    return false;
}

const char *TestToString(enum_e val)
{
    return "false";
}
```

---

There is a nice way of associating those enums to bools, you have to split it on two files .h and .cpp.
Here it is if it helps:

enum.h

```
///////////////////////////////
// enum.h
#ifdef CPP_FILE
#define ENUMBOOL_ENTRY(A, B)            { (enum_e) A, (bool) B },
struct EnumBool
{
    enum_e  enumVal;
    bool    boolVal;
};
#else
#define ENUMBOOL_ENTRY(A, B)            A,
#endif


#ifdef CPP_FILE
static EnumBool enumBoolTable[] = {
#else
enum enum_e
{
#endif
ENUMBOOL_ENTRY(ItemA, true),
ENUMBOOL_ENTRY(ItemB, false),
...
};

bool EnumToBool(enum_e val);
```

enum.cpp

```
///////////////////////////////
// enum.cpp
#define CPP_FILE
#include "enum.h"

bool EnumToBool(enum_e val)
    //implement
```

I didnt compile it so take it easy if it has any errors :).

Comment: FYI: You can't have both of those. Just one or the other.

Comment: Nitpick: `TestToString` should be returning a `const char*`.

Comment: Nitpick: `TestToString` should be returning `std::string`

Comment: Nitpick: `TestToString` should be returning `std::string_view`