# Is there a way to have an operator= for an enum?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have an enum, but I want to have an assignment operator for it to be able to assign a type that is not of the original enum.  E.g.

```
enum class X : int
{
  A, B, C, D
}

enum class Y : char
{
  A, B, C, D
}

Y& operator=(Y& lhs, X rhs)
{
  return Y = static_cast<Y>(X);
}
```

But I'm getting an `'operator =' must be a non-static member`.  Is there no way to do this?

Comment: I can't imagine a good use case for this. Can you help me out?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, the case for this is that I'm trying to update some archaic code.  They use the same constants in two different spots, but in one, it has a size of 1 byte and another it has a size of 2.  I'd rather not change the binary compatibility of the structures in case that breaks something.

Comment: If you refer to the original code as archaic, I'm guessing it's not using `enum class`, I'm guessing that's a modification you made. Is that correct? If so, would some alternative that does not use `enum class` also be acceptable?

Comment: @hvd, It is using `int` and a `char`, not even an enum.

Comment: Then Brian's answer is exactly what I would've posted. I'd give up on `enum class` if I were you, you can achieve what you want without it.

Comment: Me too. So, you see why I asked. :)

Comment: @hvd, yeah, but it is annoying.  No one would have expected a use case like that.

Comment: Turns out this won't help. Some of the code is written in C and no C++.  This would then require that I somehow get the VC compiler to compile the C code
 in C++, which could do a whole lot of unexpected things that I am not prepared to deal with at the moment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to manually define a conversion for an enum class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753543/is-it-possible-to-manually-define-a-conversion-for-an-enum-class)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot because, as the error message tells you, `operator=` can only be a non-static member function, and enums can't have members. If you really want to be able to assign from a different enum, maybe you should just make `Y` a class. Another possibility is to write a helper function to perform the assignment.

Comment: Hmmmm, that's unfortunate. :(  Making `Y` a class could make even more trouble in terms of typing...

Comment: @Adrian typing is not trouble. hidden logic errors is trouble. implicit conversions hide subtle logic errors.

Comment: By typing trouble, I mean that I'll have a 2 types per enum (class and enum) with the enum being on the 2nd level.  Which isn't horrible I guess, but annoying. `class ByteX { enum X { A, ... }; }; class WordX { enum X { A, ... }; }; class DWordX { enum X { A, ... }; };  void fn() { DWordX x = WordX::X::A; }`.  Or I guess they can all reference the Byte one, or have the Byte enum defined externally...

Answer (score 3):

An enum class is a cumbersome structure you may avoid. Just wrap an old enumeration inside a structure:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
  enum enum_type { A, B, C, D };
  typedef int value_type;
  value_type value;

  X(enum_type value) : value(value) {}
  operator enum_type () const { return static_cast<enum_type>(value); }
};

struct Y
{
  enum enum_type { A, B, C, D };
  typedef char value_type;
  value_type value;

  Y(enum_type value) : value(value) {}
  operator enum_type () const { return static_cast<enum_type>(value); }

  Y& operator = (X rhs) {
    value = rhs;
    return *this;
  }
};

int main()
{
    X x = X::A;
    Y y = Y::B;
    std::cout << y << '\n';
    y = x;
    std::cout << y << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Don't encourage hacks instead of clean solutions. An enum class is exactly what you need if you want scoped enums. Write a helper function, it's a lesser hack.

Answer (score 0):

You may write an conversion function rather than an conversion operator. In any case this is better form as it expresses intent clearly at the call site.

```
enum class X : int
{
    A, B, C, D
};

enum class Y : char
{
    A, B, C, D
};

Y to_y(X rhs)
{
    auto as_int = static_cast<int>(rhs);  // allowed
    auto as_char = static_cast<char>(as_int); // allowed if the int is known to fit
    return static_cast<Y>(as_char); // allowed if the char is known to be the right value
}

int main()
{
    auto x = X::C;

    auto y = to_y(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted it implicit as this is going to be everywhere.

Comment: if it's going to be everywhere, you absolutely do not want it to be implicit.

Comment: Yeah, I do.  The conversion is only from type `X` to type `Y` and back.  They represent the same information, but in different sizes.  They will never overflow each other.  There's absolutely no reason why it shouldn't be implicit.

Comment: so use an old-style `enum` rather than an `enum class`

Comment: No, I don't want implicit conversion to a numeric.  Only to a type of my specification.

Comment: So use an old-style `class` with  conversion and assignment  operator(s).

Comment: I understand where he's coming from. I love enum classes for their identity building uses. Rather than just "type safe", they are "purpose safe". And they are very flexible in almost every way, except for implicit conversion between "purposes". It's something I would imagine being added to the standard in the future.