# How to I write type custom conversions for enums?

Tags: c++, types, enums, casting

Let's say I have an enum like this:

```
enum fruit { apple, oranges };
```

I would like to write an operator that enables me to write

```
fruit f = fruit::apple;
std::string s = f; // "Apple"
```

For a class, I would implement a [custom cast-operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). How can I do this for an enum?

Also compare [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166434/overloading-cast-operator-for-enum-class), which (kind of) answers the question for `enum class`.

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: That is one of the reasons why the `enum class` sould be preferred. Why still insist on using a plain `enum`?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov not sure. For mee enum feels very natural. I will have a look at enum classes then

Comment: Thanks @HolyBlackCat

Comment: As Scott Meyers clearly states: "Prefer scoped enums to unscoped enums".

Comment: your custom conversion better be explicit and then there is not much difference to a free function `std::string get_string(const fruit&);`

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov this case has nothing to do with `enum` vs `enum class`. *Neither* can have members

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov [so can unscoped enums](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51c5fa84ae8097f0)

Comment: See also [how to fake it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12754639/15416)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing that would be to have a free function to do the conversion:

```
#include <cstdio>

enum class fruit { apple, oranges };  // prefer scoped enums

[[nodiscard]] constexpr char const* fruitName(fruit const f) noexcept {
  switch (f) {
    case fruit::apple: return "Apple";
    case fruit::oranges: return "Oranges";
    // most compilers will warn if you don't add all enum values
  }
  return "Error";
}

int main() {
  fruit f = fruit::apple;
  std::puts(fruitName(f));  // prints "Apple"
}
```